# App Crashing on changing tableView.contentInset

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

while setting the offsetY value to tableView contentInset

```
var offsetY: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            let oldEdgeInsets   =   self.tableView.contentInset

            self.tableView.contentInset =   UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: oldEdgeInsets.left, bottom: oldEdgeInsets.bottom, right: oldEdgeInsets.right)
        }
    }
```

I get a crash with this error below

`error: memory read failed for 0x0`

[image]

Any Solution to this?

**ADDITION**

in the initialisation method, when I set the tableview contentInset value then it works fine but after initialisation on the offsetY changes when i again change the contentInset then it crashes.

Comment: This seems like a memory management issue inside the simulator. Try restarting Xcode and the simulator itself.

Comment: @the4kman I tried restarting, it still crashes with same error

Comment: Did you try to clean the project/clean the build folder/empty Derived Data?

Comment: yes, when i comment this code app works

Comment: you can not get tableview contentInset before viewdidload call

Comment: @karthikeyan actually in the uicollectionviewcell awakeFromNib method i have set the contentInset not contentOffset and its crashing when I set on the offsetY changes

Comment: If you add print(oldEdgeInsets), does it print the right value, and error occurs only on self.tableView.contentInset =   UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: oldEdgeInsets.left, bottom: oldEdgeInsets.bottom, right: oldEdgeInsets.right) line?

Comment: Are you sure your tableView is not nil at that point? If tableView is an  IBOutlet then most likely it's an explicitly unwrapped var, so it may crash if when the nib is not loaded. Try optional unwrapping let `oldEdgeInsets = self.tableView?.contentInset ?? UIEdgeInsets.zero` or put a guard statement to avoid accessing tableView when it's nil.

Comment: Neither tableView is nil nor oldEdgeInsets is nil at that point. The error is something like `error: memory read failed for 0x0`